# how can I do the preg_match to a string with space?

Tags: php

I need to preg_match a string "a 1" 
but I only know how to preg_match "a1"

```
preg_match('{^a\d+$}',$k))
```

Can anyone tell me how to do it when the string have a space?

Comment: Have you _tried_ it with a space?

Comment: u mean just preg_match('{^a \d+$}',$k))? It doesn't work

Comment: Oh okay, that's fine then, it wasn't clear from the question that you did try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the `\s` escape          . Or literally use the space in string.. as @Ray Toal mentioned. The advantage to `\s` over  is because by using the first you can catch more than one white-space using `*` or `+` operators. `\s` catch not only (0x20) character,but `\t`,`\r`,`\v` and `\f` too.

**EDIT:**

Try this:

`preg_match('{^a\s*\d+$}','a 1');`

Check out [`this`](http://ideone.com/SebciW) online example.

Comment: @user2210819: I added on running-online exaple too. Check out my edit.

Comment: It works finally ! Its my mistake. Thank you everyone for all the suggestions and replies

Comment: @user2210819: You are welcome. If you're really happy,don't forget to mark the answer as accepted :)